# React-Native, Passing live variable(dynamic array) from one file to another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to import a dynamic array (which changes on pressing a button) from another file? 
for example: 
**file1.js** 
(please ignore syntax error in the code)

```
//this is file1.js
// here on pressing "Save" button some data is pushed in array named SavedData.

const ListTopic =["Chanakya", "Abraham Lincoln", "Albert Einstein"]
const SavedData=[]
export default class LovedScreen extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected_button:0}
  }

Saved(index){
    SavedData.push(ListTopic[index])
  }
    render() {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} onPress={() => this.Saved(index)}>
             <View style={styles.ButtonAlignment} >
                 <Image
                  source={BasketButtonNumericalValue[index] !=1 ? 
                  require('../assets/img/love_normal.png') : require('../assets/img/love_focused.png')}
                  style={styles.ImgButton} />
                  <Text> Save </Text>
                  </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
  }
```

Now in **file2.js**
here I have imported `SavedData` array from `file1.js`, component is not re rendering if `SavedData` gets changed..i.e. `SavedData` is not imported live. If I Reload the app then its render correctly for that moment.

```
//file2.js

import {SavedData} from './file1'
const empty=["You have not saved anything"]

export default class LovedScreen extends React.Component {
render() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text> {SavedData.length==0 ? empty[0] : SavedData[0]} </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Keep your variables in state, and you should pass props to child component. I recommend reading about basic concepts in React.

Comment: Thank you Dominik, But here data is dynamic  and also I want to deal with multiple objects locally at any instant. Do you have any suggestion?